# How to pass a value for variable in view in rspec controller test for rails 3.2.8 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

Here is the partial form causing the Template error in rspec controller test:

```
<%= f.label :expense_for, '栏目：'%>
<%= f.select :expense_for, @expense_for.map { |expense| [expense, expense] }, {:include_blank => true, :selected => @expense.expense_for } %>
```

We use render_views in expenses controller test. Since @expense_for is nil in create test, so .map causes error:

```
[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

The rspec code which causes the error above is:

```
get 'create', :expense => e, :expense_for => ['a','b']
```

In expenses controller, @expense_for is defined in new as:

```
  def new
    if has_create_right?
      @expense = Expense.new(params[:expense], :as => :role_new)
      if @expense.expense_type == 'production'
        @expense_for = return_expense_for_production
      elsif @expense.expense_type == 'overhead'
        @expense_for = return_expense_for_overhead
      else
        @expense_for = []
      end
    end
```

The @expense_for is filled up with ajax call.

How can I pass a value to @expense_for in partial form for rspec test? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `@expense_for` is nil in your test, then `has_create_right?` is false, so `@expense_for` is never being set. Try setting `@expense_for` to `[]` at the beginning of the action, instead of in the else clause.

Comment: Moved the @expense_for=[] to the top of method new and the error is the same. Is it because @expense_for is defined in method new and so it is nil in method create? In the rspec case, the has_create_right? is true.

Comment: @expense_for = [] if @expense_for.nil? was put in method create and it solves the nil obj problem in rspec and case passed.